# Pattern Match on `newtype`

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Given the following newtype:

`newtype Bar a = Bar { biz :: Int -> Int -> Int }`

Is it possible to pattern-match on the `Int -> Int` arguments?

Example, let's say that I'd like to pattern mach on `Bar`, and then pattern-match on the first two arguments.

```
pm :: Bar a -> Bool
pm (Bar (x y)) = x == y
```

Yet I get a compile-time error:

```
Prelude> :l NewtypeWork.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( NewtypeWork.hs, interpreted )

NewtypeWork.hs:13:10: Parse error in pattern: x
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Overall, I'm trying to understand how to `fmap` over the second argument of a function `Int -> a`. This example should, I hope, help me to understand how to accomplish this task.

Comment: The two parts of the question might not be connected in the way you're thinking. In `Bar`, the type argument `a` is never used (it's what's called a phantom type argument). As a result, the only valid `Functor` instance of `Bar` is `fmap _ b = b`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking makes sense.

This will compile:

```
pm :: Bar a -> Bool
pm (Bar f) = undefined
```

The type of `f` is `Int -> Int -> Int`. How do you propose to turn `f` into a `Bool`?

For instance, `f` might be addition of Ints - `(+)`.

An example of a valid definition of `pm` is:

```
pm (Bar f) = f 1 3 > 0
```

*Update*:

To answer the question in your comment, first consider:

```
data Foo a = Int -> a
```

then `Foo` can be made into a functor with:

(fmap f g) i = f (g i)       -- g :: Int -> a,  f :: a -> b

I.e. you are just applying `f` to the value of type `a` in `g i`.

Now you can extrapolate to this data type:

```
data Bar a = Int -> Maybe (a, Int)
```

by definition:

```
(fmap f g) i = case g i of
                 Nothing -> Nothing
                 Just (a,j) -> Just (f a, j)
```

Again, we are just applying `f` to the value of type `a` in `g i`.

Comment: Yeah I don't think it makes sense either. My question basically is how to fmap over a function `Int -> Maybe (a, Int)`

Comment: If you have `newtype T a = T (Int -> Maybe (Int, a))` then the Functor instance for `T` is `fmap f (T a) = T (fmap (fmap (fmap f)) a)`. This is because `(->) a`, `(,) a`, and `Maybe` are functors, and the composition of functors is a functor.

Comment: no doubt this comment and answer are helpful, but I'm still not completely understanding. This other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27664592/409976) might help others like me.