# Implement Functor Instance for Newtype with Function

Tags: haskell

Given the following `newtype`:

`newtype Bar a = Bar { foo :: Int -> a }`

I tried to define a `Functor` instance for it.

```
instance Functor (Bar) where
    fmap g (Bar f) = Bar $ fmap f
```

I intended to map over `Int -> a` to get `Int -> b` - I think that's the correct resultant type.

However, I got the compile-time error:

```
Couldn't match type `f0 Int' with `Int' 
Expected type: Int -> f0 a   
Actual type: f0 Int -> f0 a In the second argument of `($)', namely `fmap f' 
In the expression: Bar $ fmap f
```

How can I implement this `Functor` instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be

```
instance Functor Bar where
    fmap g (Bar f) = Bar $ fmap g f
```

I think you might have just missed the `g`.  You see `f0 Int -> f0 a` because `f :: Int -> a` so `fmap f :: Functor f0 => f0 Int -> f0 a`.  Since `g :: a -> b`, you want to `fmap g` over `f` so that `fmap g f :: Int -> b`.

Comment: Or simply `instance Functor Bar where fmap f (Bar g) = Bar (f . g)`

Comment: so, through composition `(.)`, `f . g`'s type is `(a -> Int) . (a -> b)`. Then, the resultant type is `b -> Int`.